# How to load rdf data to bigdata using nanosparqlserver

Tags: apache, http, rdf, blazegraph

I have downloaded bigdata.war and have deployed it using sesame HTTP API. Now I am not getting as to how should I load rdf triples/provenance with triples to bigdata using nanosparqlserver? I am using sesame HTTP API (using apache tomcat). Can someone please help.

I intend to use mysql, native java and postgres with sesame